# How to mask parts of overlapping UIBezierPaths

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I'm drawing a graph where there is a dot at each graph point:

[image]

To draw the graph line I'm using UIBezierPath:moveToPoint: and to draw the dots I'm drawing two circles at each point using UIBezierPath:makeCircleAtLocation:.

How can I remove the graph line where it passes through each dot? So that the dot is just pure white inside?

TIA

The  code:

```
- (void) addDotAtLocation:(CGPoint)location radius:(CGFloat)radius withInnerColor: (UIColor*) innerColor andOuterColor: (UIColor*) outerColor
{
    [outerColor setFill];
    UIBezierPath *circle = [self makeCircleAtLocation:location  radius:5.0f];
    [circle fill];
    [innerColor setFill];
    circle = [self makeCircleAtLocation:location  radius:4.0f];
    [circle fill];
}


- (UIBezierPath *) makeCircleAtLocation:(CGPoint)location radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:location
                    radius:radius
                startAngle:0.0
                  endAngle:M_PI * 2.0
                 clockwise:YES];

     return path;
}



UIBezierPath *barGraph = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];    
CGPoint plotPoint = ...
[barGraph moveToPoint:plotPoint];

for (int ii = 1; ii < [self.testData count]; ++ii)
{
    dataPoint = self.testData[ii];
    x = [self convertTimeToXPoint:dataPoint.time];
    y = [self convertDataToYPoint:dataPoint.dataUsage];
    plotPoint = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [barGraph addLineToPoint:plotPoint];
    [self addDotAtLocation:plotPoint radius:5.0 withInnerColor:[UIColor whiteColor] andOuterColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to distinguish in your mind between *constructing* a bezier path (it's just a path) and *drawing* the path (stroking and/or filling). The order in which you *draw* is the "layering" order. So you want to *stroke* your graph lines - *all* of your graph lines - first, and then and only then you want to *stroke and fill* your circles.

That is not what you are doing now. You are *constructing* the graph bezier path first, but then you are *stroking and filling* your circles and only *then* you stroke the graph path so of course it ends up "in front".

So, here's your code (condensed for clarity):

```
UIBezierPath *barGraph = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];    
[barGraph moveToPoint:plotPoint]; // this does NOT draw
for (int ii = 1; ii < [self.testData count]; ++ii)
{
    // ...
    [barGraph addLineToPoint:plotPoint]; // this does NOT draw
    [self addDotAtLocation:...]]; // THIS DRAWS!
}
// and you see we still have not drawn any of the graph lines yet
```

Thus you are clearly drawing in the opposite of the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

[circle fill];

Being circle the name of your path

Comment: Are you drawing the dot after or before the lines?

Comment: One thing I'm not doing yet is pushing/popping the context in the addDotAtLocation methods, is that needed?

Comment: Try to set the fill and stroke color inside the makeCircleAtLocation method.

Comment: That makes no difference,

Comment: What is barGraph? You're adding the Circles to self and the line to barGraph. if it's a separate CALayer, consider changing the ZPosition and sending it to the back.

Comment: barGraph is the first UIBezierPath  I mentioned in the original post. I'm not using any different layers.